# How to use SimpleAuth/Instagram in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, simple-authentication

How to use **SimpleAuth/Instagram** in **Swift**?
  How to import and use auth methods?

Comment: This is not a good question (and should be down voted). You can read how to implement it on https://github.com/calebd/SimpleAuth/wiki/Instagram. Please try and ask a real question if you get stuck.

Comment: @Tom but here is no documentation for Swift? It only for Objective-C

Comment: There are general translation rules for using Objective-C code in swift. You can read all about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for this can be found here:

http://github.com/calebd/SimpleAuth/wiki/Instagram

Translating it to Swift code can be done using the general translation rules as given in the documentation of Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/

Comment: can you look to my code. I have errors;

Comment: Thanks for information. Can you look to my code, I have errors.

Comment: Please add this code (formatted) to your original question and indicate which errors you are getting.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I fixed errors.